# Bernoulli (Binomial) and Dice probability in Risk

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

I ve solved the same problem without Bernoulli fourmula (binomial), just thinking, with 2 and 3 dice but could some of you help me to find out what is the probability of:

A) obtain with N dice attacking atleast one greather number than one Defence die? Not the sum of the N dice, but the greatest value of those N against another 1 die

B) All of them N are contemporary greater than the defense die?

If you want we can call the last one die D (Defense) and we can say that the  others N dice are attacking

Without Bernoulli i ve found out with 2 dice A) $$1-\sum_{1}^{6} (\frac{k}{6})^{2} \cdot \frac{1}{6} $$

And B) $$\sum_{1}^{6} (1-\frac{k}{6})^{2} \cdot \frac{1}{6}$$
Please I need it so bad with Bernoulli or with the probability of Maximum

Comment: [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3015796/probably-of-winning-with-n-dice-maximum-of-them-with-bernoulli) was asked earlier using a different user name.  At the time, people pointed out that the question wasn't clear.

Comment: in this case we need to find the odds in a generic way for N dice, with Bernoulli formula

Comment: The rules for $A$ are not clear.  For $B$, your answer appears to be complete (just replace $2$ with $N$).

Comment: If, in $A$, you are asking for the probability that the max of the $N$ dice exceeds the isolated die, then note that (as in $B$) the probability that all the $N$ dice are $≤k$ is $\left( \frac k6 \right)^N$ so the probability that the max equals $k$ is the difference $\left( \frac k6 \right)^N- \left( \frac {k-1}6 \right)^N$

Comment: How could I implement it with Bernoulli trial formula: $$ P(z)=\binom{n}{z}\cdot p^{z}\cdot q^{n-z} ? $$

Comment: That's the part that doesn't make sense...why are you insisting on using that formula?  It doesn't appear to be helpful.

Comment: I know and this is the problem, I have to use it by instruction by my teacher

Comment: Well, if $k$ is fixed, the you can regard a die coming up $≤k$ as a Bernoulli process with success probability $\frac k6 $.  The probability that all $N$ meet this condition can then be read off using the formula you mentioned.